# setup samba share on 10.10 and access via windows

Tags: 10.10, windows, samba, file-sharing

I have the following `/etc/samba/smb.conf` config setup to share my `homes` and a custom folder named `/var/itc_data_feed`:

```
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
   read only = no

[itc_data_feed]
   comment = ITC_DATA_FEED
   path = /var/itc_data_feed
   read only = No
```

After editing this file I restarted smbd with the following command:

```
sudo smbd reload
```

I would expect to be able to access these on windows OSs through Start->Run: `\\myservername\someuser` or `\\myservername\itc_data_feed` but neither are working.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

It seems that I cannot connect using the servername but rather I must use IP address.  Once I use IP address I am asked to authenticate with my linux credentials; however, I am wanting an open share that does not require authentication.

To achieve this I intentionally omitted the `valid users` line but I am still being asked to authenticate, why is this happening?

Comment: Barely on topic but I think you want `writable = yes` instead of `read only = no`. You might also eventually (once it's working) want `valid users = %S` to limit access to homes based on the samba user.

Comment: @Oli, please see my update in my OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I may have solved my problem:

my smb.conf now has these changes in the following sections:

```
security = share

create mask = 0757

[itc_data_feed]
  comment = ITC_DATA_FEED
  path = /var/itc_data_feed
  writable = yes
  browsable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  create mask = 0757
```

these settings allow me to connect directly to the /var/itc_data_feed share without needing to authenticate and gives the user read/write permissions in the directory.